# What is the difference between DateTime.UtcNow and DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()

Tags: c#

To me they're both the same. Is UtcNow simply a shortcut?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually it's the other way around. The `Now` property is implemented as:

```
public static DateTime Now {
  get {
    return UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
  }
}
```

Comment: So doing DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() is the same as UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime()

Comment: @Anthony not at all, see my answer (a bit late)

Comment: What about `DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime()` Does it apply UTC conversion twice?

Comment: @Joel: No, if you use `ToUniversalTime` on a `DateTime` value that is already UTC, it will just return the value unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't a shortcut, DateTime.Now uses DateTime.UtcNow internally and then applies localization. In short, use ToUniversalTime() if you already have DateTime.Now and need to convert it to UTC, use DateTime.UtcNow if you just want to retrieve the current time in UTC.

Comment: Devs should also note, you want to use the DateTime.UtcNow on machines that are in UTC otherwise I have seen oddities.  This is particularly the case for my Azure WebJobs.

Answer (score 5):

There is a long example in the [Documentation for UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) which shows them to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the actual implementation is (you can see it on [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,908)):

```
public static DateTime Now {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<DateTime>().Kind == DateTimeKind.Local);

        DateTime utc = UtcNow; 
        Boolean isAmbiguousLocalDst = false;
        Int64 offset = TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(utc, out isAmbiguousLocalDst).Ticks;
        long tick = utc.Ticks + offset;
        if (tick>DateTime.MaxTicks) {
            return new DateTime(DateTime.MaxTicks, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        if (tick<DateTime.MinTicks) {
            return new DateTime(DateTime.MinTicks, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        return new DateTime(tick, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousLocalDst);  
    }
}
```

`ToUniversalTime()` calls `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(this, TimeZoneInfoOptions.NoThrowOnInvalidTime)`

while UtcNow is just:

```
long ticks = 0;
ticks = GetSystemTimeAsFileTime();
return new DateTime( ((UInt64)(ticks + FileTimeOffset)) | KindUtc);
```

Comment: If you look at the implementation of `ToLocalTime` you will see that the current implementation of `Now` is mostly just a manually inlined and somewhat simplified version of `return UtcNow.ToLocalTime();`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using DateTime.UTCNow would consider the DateTime.Kind property's value as UTC whereas with ToUniversalTime you can provide the Kind property with a local datetime object.