# DateTime on local machine is different then Azure

Tags: azure, datetime, datetime-format

I know this might be a simple question but I'm not sure how to solve it.

When I run this bit of code on my local machine

```
if (someDateTime < DateTime.Now)
   // do something
```

'DateTime.Now' gives me the current date time for my time zone, but when I run it in Azure 'DateTime.Now' gives me a different time

ex. local machine says 12:00AM and Azure says 8:13AM

What do I need to do to compare a time 'someDAteTime' with a time for a user on my site (his/her current DateTime.Now) ?

Comment: Do you know the user's timezone? Azure servers by default run in UTC. If you know the users timezone, you can convert your `someDateTime` into UTC and then make your comparison.

Comment: Hi Dan. I guess I could get the users timezone, but I want to make sure I can schedule 'classes' correctly and send emails to students 24 hours before the class. I'm sending a message to a Azure queue to trigger a function to run 24 hours before the class starts to remind registered students. So the message has to trigger the function 24 hours before the class time of the users local time. So I guess if I convert everything in the app to UTC is should be good right?

Comment: That's right. In general with cloud programming - convert everything to UTC, implement your business logic in UTC, then convert to local time on the way to the client.

Comment: to convert to local time on the way back to the client is there a easy way to do that or do I have to save the time zone of the client in a table to fetch later?

Comment: If your users are all in different time zones, then yes, you ought to save it somewhere on your users table (or whatever).

Comment: do you recommend I get the time zone locally in javascript or can I get it server side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161771/discussion-between-dan-schnau-and-user1186050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a `Utc()` method on that `DateTime` instance, every programming language has something similar since probably the Atari.

If this is .NET (Full/Core), just use [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx).
More on that here — 
[What is the difference between DateTime.UtcNow and DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607308/what-is-the-difference-between-datetime-utcnow-and-datetime-now-touniversaltime)

The essence here is that you always compare UTC time to UTC time, disregarding zone shift. Moreover, all Azure services [report time in UTC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/moving-to-coordinated-universal-time-utc/) "out of the box".

Comment: ya I see the 'ToUniversalTime()' method. So should I be converting all time coming into my app to UTC? something like ' eventDateTime.UTC() < DateTime.Now'

Comment: I guess that's a yes, just convert everything to UTC and work from that?

Comment: Sure thing. Assuming all comparison is done server side. Client side (probably JavaScript) is of course full of snakes, but still you should strive for UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using javascript at client side.

If you want to compare dates you should always use ISO Date (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)with a timezone.

You can use this library in order to use different time zones: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

And this library to compare dates:
https://momentjs.com/

Please take care that the user can modify the date on the client side, so if you need to validate a date for a critical feature you should do this validation on the server side.

Comment: essentially what I'm doing is I have a scheduling app where the user can schedule classes in a calendar. They pick a date and time and that gets saved in a db. then I have Azure functions that are triggered from a message queue in different cases (ex. 24 hours before the class event date time) to do something. So this has to be triggered 24 hours before the date time of the user's date time scheduled class, wherever they are